# Hosting a Java Skype Bot

Tags: java, hosting, bots, skype

So I have created a very basic show-off type of bot, it runs off of the Skype API and requires Skype to be running in order for it to work properly. I have tested the bot by hosting it off of my own computer no problem, the issue is that I don't want to have my computer running 24/7. That's why I looked at OVH.com for hosting. I would like to get a small $3 VPS and host the bot off of that. I have tried on my other servers with them (Centos/Debian) to get Skype running but it seems to be quite the struggle. So in end I need something (OS/Program/Whatever) to get this bot hosted on an OVH vps using one of their provided operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have Skype installed on your VPS, which also requires that you have a Desktop package setup along with VNC to configure skype. You might find this article on how to setup SevaBot, a Skype bot, useful for how to setup and install the necessary programs, https://github.com/opensourcehacker/sevabot/blob/master/docs/source/ubuntu.rst#id8. Keep in mind that if you are running both skype and a extensive Java program, a really cheap VPS might not cut it. I know my VPS wasn't able to handle my skype bot running in large chats, but it was only a 256mb VPS, so that may have contributed.